# Access array of server side in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a pie chart for which I want to populate the data. I have been able to set the data in jQuery like this

```
var data = [
        { label: "Abc", data: 12 },
        { label: "xyz", data: 15 },
        { label: "Setwet", data: 85 },
        { label: "DashOut", data: 30 },           
    ];
```

I want to be able to set the same data from my code behind file from database, and access it in jQuery. How can I do that?

My database does have all the information. I have created a class with two members label and data. I have created a collection of this class and added values from database table to this collection like this

```
    private List<myData> _myData;
    public List<myData> MyData
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myData == null)
            {
                _myData = new List<myData>();
                _myData.Add(new myData() { label = "abc", data = "10" });
                _myData.Add(new myData() { label = "def", data = "20" });
            }
            return _myData;
        }
        set { _myData = value; }
    }
```

My jQuery is expecting an array but in code i have created a Collection of user defined class. Will that be ok? or how should I go about it?

Comment: You need to return json encoded string e.g. in php json_encode($array)

Comment: any sample? I return json encoded string from code behind but how do I access it in client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several forms to do this. Can convert (serialize) `MyData` to json using `JavaScriptSerializer` and save in hidden field:

```
hiddenfield.Value = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MyData)
```

then, can access to this from client-side:

```
var data = $("hiddenfield").val();
```

Can use [WebMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and use javascript from server-side.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this (should be pasted into a cshtml file):

```html
@{
    //any data structure, generated on server side
    var data = new List<string>{
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc"
    };
    
    //the serialization to JSON happens here
    var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
    
}
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var jsSideData = @Html.Raw(json);

        for (var i = 0; i < jsSideData.length; i++){
            alert(jsSideData[i]);
        }

    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP is not using the `ASP.NET MVC` with `Razor HTML`. Your answer is irrelevant with the OP's question. OP tagged the question in `ASP.NET` not in `ASP.NET MVC`.

Answer (score 0):

Server side (I don't know asp hence php code here)

// write your own query
//your query from database here, $num is database result object

```
               $arr= array(
                    "id" => $num->id,
                    "name" => $num->name,
                    "Response" => "Login Successfull !",
               );
 echo json_encode($arr);
```

// then in js code make get request and use returned data to loop

```
 function ajaxUsersData() {
    var city = 5;//if you want to send some variable
    jQuery.get('http://yoursite.com/index.php', {city: city}, function (data) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            jQuery(function () {
                var content = '';
                for (var j = 0; j < json.length; j++) {
                    content += '<tr id="' + json[j].id + '">';
                    content += '<td>' + json[j].name + '</td>';
                    content += '<td>' + json[j].response + '</td>';
                    content += '</tr>';
                }
                jQuery('#yourhtmlToChange').html(content);
            });
        });
   }
```